# Is it natural to say "exchange contacts"?

Tags: phrase-usage, colloquial-language

Example:

> She wanted to *exchange contacts* with him. (e.g. email, instant
> messaging, phone number.)

Is it natural to use this phrase? As a short way of saying: "exchange contact information?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would depend what you wanted from the other person.

- *My 'contacts'* would be the information I hold about *other people*.
- *My contact information* is my own personal details.